# Unprotecting multiple workbooks VBA

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am trying to unlock multiple `Excel Workbooks` from within a file. I know the password and it's the same for all files.

I run the following code. It works in the sense that I don't get an error message and that all the right workbooks are opened and then closed. However when I try opening the files manually after running the code I am still asked for a password.

My `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect` doesn't work on its own and I really don't understand why because I haven't seen a different syntax across the internet.

This is my code:

```
Sub Hell3()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            Workbooks.Open (xFdItem & xFileName), Password:="pass"
            ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="pass"
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If

    Dim macrowb As String
    macrowb = "Book1.xlsm"
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If WB.Name <> macrowb Then
            WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    Next WB
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use markdown conventions to format your code the correct way.

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated normally

Comment: What if you try `Set WB = Workbooks.Open (xFdItem & xFileName), Password:="pass"` followed by `WB.Unprotect "pass"`?

Comment: I tried this but you are not allowed the comma and password option with Set I believe (I get "unexpected end of statement")

Comment: @clara ...Use the code in the answer. This will save all the unprotected files in a new folder in the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Work:

```
Sub Hell3()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        MkDir xFdItem & "\Password Removed Files"
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open((xFdItem & xFileName), Password:="pass")

                WB.SaveAs Filename:=xFdItem & "Password Removed Files\" & xFileName, FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

                WB.Close True

            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If


End Sub
```

Will Create a New Folder with the Password Removed Files

Answer (score 2):

Using ActiveWorkbook can often to lead to problems. That's why the general advice is to avoid it, and instead refer to each workbook explicitly. You're assuming that when a workbook is opened, it is made the Active one.

Edit: since you have now clarified that it's the *file protection* you want to remove (not the Workbook protection), you need to use SaveAs, and remove the password protection from the file - as below

Try this:

```
Do While xFileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName, Password:="pass")
    wb.Unprotect Password:="pass" ' This explicitly unprotects the opened workbook.
    xFileName = Dir
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=xFdItem & xFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook, Password:=""
Loop
```

More information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

Comment: This is not doing what is required. It's working the same as original code.

Comment: Just to check: you are talking about protecting the workbook, not the *file* - right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris, but running your code I have the same issue that it runs fine but that when I try opening a file afterwards I still get the message " 'file.xlsx' is protected. Password:"

Comment: By file I mean the .xlsx object that is within my folder

Comment: @clara - Your question was based on workbook protection. This relates to forbidding users from adding/deleting sheets etc, and is indeed managed in VBA by using the wb.Protect and wb.Unprotect methods. However you have now clarified that your workbooks are *password protected* as in, a password is required to open the files themselves - which you want to remove. This is a different matter. You need to use .SaveAs, as above.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, it worked I believed altough I was getting different error messages during execution